# Write a query to get an array and use that array in a subquery

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, subquery

What I am trying to do is get the results from the first query pass them into an array and then use them in a sub query. Both queries work separately if I input the id's into the sub query manually. Is there a way of linking these two queries?

I have used this code

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT v2.video_id as v2id FROM VideoTags AS v1 JOIN VideoTags AS v2 USING ( tag_id ) WHERE v1.video_id =1 AND v1.video_id <> v2.video_id GROUP BY v2.video_id ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC"); 

$values = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
  $values[] = $row['v2id'];
}

echo join(", ", $values);

$resultone = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE video_id IN (' . join(',', $values). ')"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $resultone )) {
  echo "name ".$row['video_name'];
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You know the `join()` in the second query is inside the wrong speech marks, you are using single quotes to break out of double quotes.

Comment: From what i understand, you want your mysql query return the very same rows you have got from the 1st query. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called subquery (and what you use is not subquery, because it does not contain one query inside another.

```
SELECT * 
FROM videos 
WHERE video_id IN (
    SELECT v2.video_id 
    FROM VideoTags AS v1 
    JOIN VideoTags AS v2 USING ( tag_id ) 
    WHERE v1.video_id =1 AND v1.video_id <> v2.video_id 
    GROUP BY v2.video_id ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is enough

```
$resultone = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE video_id IN (SELECT v2.video_id as v2id FROM VideoTags AS v1 JOIN VideoTags AS v2 USING ( tag_id ) WHERE v1.video_id =1 AND v1.video_id <> v2.video_id GROUP BY v2.video_id ORDER BY COUNT (*) DESC)"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $resultone )) {
  echo "name ".$row['video_name'];
}
```

But before using query like this, check your mysql version for subquery support.

Comment: do you have a link or documentation to back that statement up?  I have found that joins perform better than sub-queries...

Comment: @Leslie: Sorry, i didn't mean that sub queries is better in all situation but in this case it is better than join. join is also good but in this case join() is not better because we know the values to be filtered. if found this when i googld in the past. here what i remeber: join() compare each row with the each row of the opposite table, if table1 has 10 rows and table2 has 10 rows in join() it does 10*10 that is 100 scenarios. but in sub query it fetches and check with it so it has only 10 scenarios + subquery exec time. please advise me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in one query.

```
$innersql = "SELECT v2.video_id FROM VideoTags AS v1 JOIN VideoTags AS v2 USING ( tag_id ) WHERE v1.video_id =1 AND v1.video_id <> v2.video_id GROUP BY v2.video_id ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC"); 

$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE video_id IN (" . $innersql .")"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $resultone )) {
  echo "name ".$row['video_name'];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM VideoTags AS v1 JOIN VideoTags AS v2 USING ( tag_id )   
inner join video vi on vi.video_id = v1.video_id   
WHERE v1.video_id =1 AND v1.video_id <> v2.video_id GROUP BY v2.video_id ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC");
```

The count(*) does not make sence ?